# Isit possible to prevent an OS (dual boot) to access/mount any other partition?

Tags: partitioning, security

Suppose I have a computer with a few OS-es

```
Partition 1: Manjaro Linux
Partition 2: Windows
Partition 3: Ubuntu Linux
Partition 4: Data
```

And I want to disallow Ubuntu from accessing/mounting any other drives. Isit possible? I think one way is encrypting the other drives? Any other way?

The context is I want to try setting up my work security software like JumpCloud/VPN but don't want anyone to try to access any other data.

Comment: You can mount partitions & set them to not be mounted unless using sudo & also can change permissions to prevent use. Of course any user with access to system can revert settings or use live installer to mount them. noauto in fstab: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047109/how-can-i-delay-mount-of-secondary-internal-hard-drive-on-boot?noredirect=1#comment1710066_1047109

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On x86/x64, the operating system has full access to the system and underlying hardware. Unless you disable these drives in BIOS, the OS will be able to access them (and in fact, with UEFI the OS theoretically can enable them again).

Drive encryption is a possible solution, as is running the Ubuntu in a virtual machine. If you split the operating systems across different physical drives, you could disconnect the cables.

Besides that; I highly doubt that any security software would be searching for unmounted partitions, mount them and then start scanning them.

Comment: Some of these seem to allow admin to control ur OS? Or at least it sounds like. I will consider the BIOS option perhaps. Physically unplugging is abit too troublesome. Encrypting seems possible but abit troublesome at this point

Comment: If the work security software is running with admin privileges, they are lord and master on your system. It just depends on how far you want to take it and how much trouble that's worth for you.

Comment: Ok understood. Thank you for the explaination